# Como faço pra enviar e-mail transacional no AWS?

Tags: php, envio-de-email, ubuntu, email, amazon-aws

Utilizo um servidor Ubuntu no AWS e não consigo rodar a função mail() do PHP.
É preciso instalar algo no servidor ou configurar algo no AWS Console?

Comment: Tente instalar um servidor de email local, segue abaixo link com tutorial de instalação/configuração do postfix; http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/Postfix

Answer (score 7):

### Limitações relacionadas ao envio de emails a partir de instâncias do EC2

Se você estiver tentando enviar emails diretamente a partir de instâncias do EC2 -- isto é, sem usar o serviço SES (Simple Email Service) --, provavelmente terá os disparos bloqueados após uma certa quantidade de emails.

Isso ocorre pois a AWS tem bastante interesse em não permitir que usuários "manchem a reputação" dos IPs públicos, caso algum usuário tente enviar SPAM a partir das instâncias do EC2, já que isso seria prejudicial a todos os outros clientes.

A recomendação é realmente utilizar o serviço SES, pois ele trás diversas vantagens brevemente enumeradas a seguir.

Veja mais informações no [**FAQ do EC2**](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances).

### Envio de emails através do SES (Simple Email Service)

O SES facilita diversas tarefas relacionadas ao disparo de emails. Usando o SES, você conta com:

- notificações de *bounces*;
- notificações de *complaints*;
- notificações de *rejects*;
- facilidade para configurar SPF e DKIM transparente (se usar Route53)

Há duas formas principais de utilizar o SES: diretamente através de chamadas de API (ex: SendMail), ou através dos endpoints SMTP.

Veja [**esta página da documentação (em inglês)**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-app.html) que mostra um exemplo de código PHP que dispara emails através do SES. Essa página linka para uma outra que ensina a [**configurar o Postfix para disparar emails através do SES**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html).

Outra forma de realizar os disparos, sem a necessidade de configurar o Postfix, é através do uso do PHPMailer. Você pode especificar um servidor SMTP que o PHPMailer utilizará para disparar os emails (em contraste com a função mail(), que utilizará um SMTP local). Assim, você pode configurar o endpoint SMTP do SES diretamente no PHPMailer, sem a necessidade de instalar e configurar o Postfix. Veja nas outras respostas exemplo de código usando o PHPMailer.

Ao iniciar o uso do SES, você estará numa *sandbox* e só poderá disparar até 200 emails por dia apenas para destinatários de "teste" (que deverão confirmar que aceitam receber os seus emails através de uma notificação do próprio SES).

Para sair da sandbox e ganhar *production access*, você deve preencher um simples formulário. Em geral, o processo é rápido. Ao sair da sandbox, inicialmente você poderá enviar 5000 emails por dia. Caso você se mantenha próximo desse limite, e mantenha bem reduzidas as taxas de *bounce* e *complaints*, o limite será automaticamente aumentado, aos poucos, até 1M/dia. Caso precise disparar mais do que 1M de emails, o processo é manual e você deve explicar o seu caso de uso para o suporte.

Veja mais informações na [**página do SES**](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/) e no [**User Guide (DKIM) - em inglês**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dkim.html).

### Envio de emails diretamente através de instâncias do EC2

Existem alguns casos de uso em que é realmente necessário disparar emails a partir de instâncias do EC2. Se você realmente tiver essa necessidade, alguns passos são necessários:

1. Alocar Elastic IPs para as instâncias que dispararão emails.
2. Pedir para o suporte configurar DNS reverso para esses EIPs.
3. Pedir para o suporte aumentar o limite de disparo de emails a partir de instâncias do EC2.

Será necessário explicar para o suporte o seu caso de uso para ter o seu pedido atendido. Note que a configuração de SPF e DKIM não poderá ser facilitada pelo SES/Route53 nesse caso, e será de sua responsabilidade -- não é obrigatório, mas a taxa de entrega pode ser fortemente prejudicada sem a configuração e a implementação corretas desses dois mecanismos de proteção de SPAM.

O link para o formulário pode ser encontrado no [**FAQ do EC2 linkado anteriormente**](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/faqs/#Are_there_any_limitations_in_sending_email_from_EC2_instances).

Answer (score 2):

Voce precisa instalar um servidor SMTP no servidor ou usar o serviço SES de AWS que pode configurar no AWS Console. Eu recomendo usar o componente [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)    em vez da função mail() pois é mais fácil de configurar

Answer (score 2):

Tem aqui este [vídeo que explica direitinho como proceder](http://vimeo.com/78288318) (minuto 48:30).

Se não quiser utilizar o serviço SES na Amazon AWS, precisa de um servidor SMTP e da biblioteca [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Utilizando a bliblioteca PHPMailer só precisa verificar quais os dados do seu servidor de email. Por exemplo:

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 1 para aparecer erros e mensagens relacionados com o SMTP, 0 para não aparecerem erros nem mensagens, 2 para mensagens apenas
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "http";
$mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; //neste caso uso a minha conta na Godaddy
$mail->Port = 80; 

$mail->Username = "<seu nome>";
$mail->Password = "<sua senha>";
$mail->From = "<seu email>";
$mail->FromName = "<seu nome>";
$mail->AddAddress("<email destinatário>", "<nome destinatário>");
$mail->AddReplyTo("<seu email>", "<seu nome>");

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters

$anexo = "pasta/all.zip"; //caso pretenda enviar anexos

$mail->AddAttachment($anexo, "dados.zip"); // caso queira adicionar um nome diferente ao arquivo de anexo
$mail->IsHTML(true); // se pretender enviar no formato HTML

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/logo.png', 'logo'); //para enviar como logotipo de assinatura
$mail->Subject = "<Assunto>";
$mail->Body    = "A sua mensagem... <a href=\"http://www.seusite.com.br\"><img src=\"cid:logo\" alt=\"Título de seu site\"></a>";
if($mail->Send())
  echo "Enviado com sucesso";
else
  echo "Erro ao enviar email";
```

Comment: Obrigado amigos!