# Enviar email em massa usando Amazon SES

Tags: php, email, amazon-aws, ses

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que deve enviar emails em massa usando o serviço da Amazon SES.

**Como é feito o envio**

Para enviar email, estou usando o PHP Mailer, com o seguinte código:

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '{HOST DO SES}';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = '{USERNAME DO SES}';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '{PASSWORD DO SES}';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->From = 'notify@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Site name';
$mail->addAddress( $email );  // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('notify@domain.com', 'Site name');

$mail->WordWrap = 80;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Seu amigo(a) ' . $AuthUser->name . ' te indicou';
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = 'Mensagem alternativo texto puro.';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    throw new FwException( 'Erro ao enviar convite para "' .$email . '" do usuário' );
}
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

Como possibilito que o usuário importe uma lista TXT com vários emails, tenho o risco de ter um número alto de Bounces, isto é, muitos emails inválidos na lista importada. Se eu tiver um indice de retorno por emails inválidos, meu usuário poderá ser bloqueado. Para isso eu valido antes de enviar usando o uma classe que encontrei no [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/).

Algumas dicas sobre validação de email, encontrei [aqui no Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8067/como-verificar-se-um-email-existe-mesmo?rq=1)

Usando este tipo de método consigo remover a maior parte dos emails inválido. Este não funciona para servidores que retornam o código 200 para o comando `RCPT TO` enviado para o servidor de SMTP do email testado. Sendo assim para toda a validação envio o email que desejo testar e se ele me retornar 200, envio um email que provavelmente não irá existir, como "nome567890123jhjasjhdkasdl@dominio.com".

Para enviar os emails, eu recupero os emails válidos e executo o código de envio um por um dando um sleep de 1 segundo entre cada um.

**Configuração do SES**

O Meu SES me disponibiliza 10.000 emails em 24 horas e 5 emails a cada segundo.

Configurei o domínio e habilitei o DKIM.

Validei um endereço válido do domínio configurado.

Segui as recomendações para configurar o SES na amazon, seguindo as informações que podem ser envontradas [aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2912/como-faco-pra-enviar-e-mail-transacional-no-aws/2941#2941).

Possuo duas instâncias de EC2, um para serviço e outro para o sistema. Onde o de serviço possui IP fixo e o de sistema não. Os emails são validados e enviados pela instância do sistema.

**Dúvidas**

1. A amazon possui alguma maneira fácil de enviar a lista de emails e ela gerenciar a fila de envio?
2. Se não tiver, a única forma é via script como mostrei acima?
3. O código de validação de email pode fazer com que eu entre para a BlackList de alguns servidores, devido ao alto número de requisição para o servidor de SMTP. Soube deste risco pelos serviços especializados em validação de email existentes no mercado como o [Bulk Email Verifier](http://bulkemailverifier.com/features/) e [Mail Chimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-cant-i-use-mailchimp-to-clean-my-list/).

   Este risco é verdadeiro? Existe possibilidade de driblar este problema?

Comment: Acho que vale a pena dar uma lida no SDK da Amazon para PHP http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html

Comment: Eu cheguei a ler, mas no [SDK fala que devo dividir o envio em 50 emails e fazer várias requisições](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail). Porem não posso enviar a lista completa e eles gerenciarem a fila de envio. A validação de email, parece que [eles fornecem esse serviço](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_verifyDomainIdentity), se funcionar o problema vai ser apenas gerenciar a fila mesmo. Tenho uma ideia usando o CRON, mas queria evitar usar devido a complexidade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depois de estudar muito as várias maneiras que pude encontrar na WEB para o controle de envio em massa utilizando o [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/) cheguei em uma maneira simples e de fácil controle. E preferi utilizar um solução dom o SDK da Amazon.

Para começar a amazon não possui no serviço SES, meios de gerenciar filas de envio, então optei por usar o CRON e dividir os envios em pequenos lotes.

Elaborei uma interface para controlar o `CRON` pelo `PHP`, de modo que posso agendar tarefas registrando informações de um formulário `HTML` e processando pelo `PHP`. Isso tambem permite que minha tabela do `CRON` fique com apenas uma tarefa que irá executar um script que verificará as tarefas do meu sistema.

Para isso criei uma tabela no banco de dados (estou usando MySQL). Registrando as tarefas no banco de dados posso facilmente habilitar e desabilitar uma tarefa, assim como alterá-la quando for necessário.

```
CREATE TABLE `cron_task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `minute` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `hour` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `weekday` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `first_execution` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_execution` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Utilizei uma interface para padronizar minhas classes de tarefas.

```
interface ICronTask {
    public static function add( ICronTask $task );
    public function activate();
    public function deactivate();
    public function executeTask();
    public function makeLog( $content );
}
```

Onde o método `add` serve para salvar uma tarefa, `activate` e `deactivate` para ativar e desativar a tarefa, `executeTask` conterá o contexto de execução da tarefa, seja envio de email, requisição de url, backup, ou seja lá o que mais, e o método `makeLog` para gerar logs personalizados para a execução das tarefas.

Criei uma classe abstrata para implementar os métodos básicos para todas as tarefas.

```
abstract class CronTask implements ICronTask {
    public $id;
    public $description;

    public $minute;
    public $hour;
    public $day;
    public $month;
    public $year;
    public $weekday;

    public $type;
    public $priority;

    public $active;
    public $first_execution;
    public $last_execution;

    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;

    public $execution_start;
    public $execution_end;

    public function __construct( $id = null ) {
        // caso o $id possua valor, busco informações no banco sobre a tarefa
        // e preencho todos os atributos.
    }

    public final static function add( ICronTask $task ) {
        // Salvo no banco de dados e chamo o método save()
    }

    public final function activate() {
        // Atualizo a tarefa no banco para ativar
    }

    public final function deactivate() {
        // Atualizo a tarefa no banco para desativar
    }

    public final function makeLog( $content ) {
        // Salvo o log da tarefa
    }

    public final function executeTask() {
        // Executo a tarefa
        $this->execution_start = round( microtime(true), 4 );
        $content = $this->execute();
        $this->execution_end = round( microtime(true), 4 );
        $this->makeLog($content);
    }

    public final function isNow() {
        // Faço a verificação da hora de execução, garantindo que deve ser executada
        // no momento em que for chamado.
        return (
            $this->parserTime($this->minute, 'i')   &&
            $this->parserTime($this->hour, 'H')     &&
            $this->parserTime($this->month, 'm')    &&
            $this->parserTime($this->day, 'd')      &&
            $this->parserTime($this->weekday, 'w')
        );
    }

    private function parserTime( $value, $element ) {
        // Obtem o tem atual
    $time = date( $element );

    // Verifica se o valor é igual à "*" representando toda momento.
    if( $value == '*' ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Separa os conjuntos de tempos separados por vírgula
    $groups = explode( ',', $value );
    foreach ( $groups as $part ) {
        // Verifica se é um intervalo composto. Ex: "*/5" ou "20-40/2"
        // Se é um intervalo compost, deverá retornar true se o valor atual
        // estiver dentro do intervalo definido antes da barra, e na frequência
        // definida após a barra.
        if( strpos( $part, '/' ) ) {
            $groupsInterval = explode( '/', $part );
            // Verificando a frequência
            $frequency = $time % $groupsInterval[1] == 0;

            // Verificando o intervalo
            $interval = explode( '-', $groupsInterval[0] );
            $intervalResult = false;
            if( $interval[0] == '*' ) {
                $intervalResult = true;
            } else {
                $intervalResult = ( $time >= $interval[0] && $time <= $interval[1] );
            }
            return $frequency && $intervalResult;
        }

        // Verifica se é um intervalo simples. Ex: "10-50"
        // Se é um intervalo, deverá retornar true se o valor atual estiver
        // dentro desse intervalo.
        if( strpos( $part, '-' ) ) {
            $interval = explode( '-', $part );
            return $time >= $interval[0] && $time <= $interval[1];
        }

        // Se for um número simples verifica se é o tempo certo
        if( $time == $part ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    abstract protected function execute();
    abstract protected function save();
}
```

E um exemplo de implementação de uma classe de tarefas seria

```
class CronTaskTest extends CronTask {
    public $type = 'Test';
    public $priority = 0;

    protected function execute() {
        return 'Tarefa executada com sucesso';
    }

    protected function save() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A classe principal que será executada a todo instante verificando as tarefas ficou implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
class Cron {
    public static function execute() {
        $tasks = self::getTasks();
        foreach ( $tasks as $task ) {
            if( $task->isNow() ) {
                $task->executeTask();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getTasks() {
        try {
            $tasks = // Busco todas as tarefas ativas ordenadas por prioridade DESC;

            $return = array();
            foreach ( $tasks as $record ) {
                $taskName = 'CronTask' . $record['type'];
                require_once __DIR__ . '/tasks/' . $taskName . '.php';
                $return[] = new $taskName( $record['id'] );
            }
        } catch ( PDOException $exception ) {
            die( $exception->getMessage() );
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Crio um arquivo PHP para executar as tarefas chamando o método `Cron::execute()`.
E agendo no CRON

```
# crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/projeto/meu-script.php
```

Sendo assim criei uma classe chamada `CronTaskMailing` semelhante ao exemplo acima com os próprios atributos

```
public $name;
public $subject;
public $body;
public $alternativeBody;
public $startSend;
public $notifyTo;
public $keywords = array();
public $addresses = array();
public $sended = array();

public $startedAt;
public $completedAt;
```

Estes atributos eu salvo em um `json`. Para isso implementei a lógica no método `save` que é chamado logo quando a tarefa é adicionada. Tambem implemente outro método para carregar as informações do `json` salvo para os atributos da classe.

Implementei um método para tratar toda a mensagem que será passada para a SDK da Amazon.

```
private function makeMessage() {
    $msg = array();
    $msg['Source'] = "notify@clubespin.com";

    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = $this->subject;
    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";

    $msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = $this->alternativeBody;
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";

    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $this->body;
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";

    return $msg;
}
```

Defini uma média máxima de uso do SES para mailing, evitando que outros serviços que tambem utilizam o SES não fiquem impossibilitados de usar. Esta cota está definida em porcentagem para facilitar as contas.

```
const MAX_QUOTA_USAGE = 0.8;
```

E o método de execução da tarefa ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
protected function execute() {
    $log = '';
    try {
        $this->loadMailingFile( $this->id );
        $ses = SesClient::factory( array(
            'key' => 'ACCESS_KEY',
            'secret' => 'API_SECRET',
            'region' => 'REGION'
        ) );

        if( $this->startedAt ) {
            $this->startedAt = time();
        }

        $msg = $this->makeMessage();

        // Obtenho a minha cota e verifico se está dentro da média máxima definida.
        $quota = $ses->getSendQuota();
        $maxQuota = $quota['Max24HourSend'] * self::MAX_QUOTA_USAGE;

        if( $maxQuota < $quota['SentLast24Hours'] ) {
            $log .= 'Cota máxima para mailing em 24 horas excedida.';
        } else {
            // Calculo o delay entre uma mensagem e outra para não 
            // estourar o número de envios por segundo.
            $rate = $quota['MaxSendRate'];
            $delay = $quota['MaxSendRate'] / 1000000;
            // Calculo o tamanho do lote para que a execução dure no máximo um minuto.
            $maxSendBatch = $rate * 60;

            $count = 0;
            foreach ( $this->addresses as $key => $email ) {
                $msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array( $email );
                $response = $ses->sendEmail( $msg );
                $messageId = $response->get( 'MessageId' );
                $log .= 'Mensagem enviada: ' . $messageId . PHP_EOL;

                $this->sended[] = array(
                    'email' => $email,
                    'message_id' => $messageId,
                    'sended_at' => time()
                );
                unset( $this->addresses[$key] );

                $count++;
                if( $count == $maxSendBatch ) {
                    break;
                }
                usleep($delay);
            }
            $log .= '-----' . PHP_EOL;
            $log .= 'Total de emails enviados: ' . count( $this->sended ) . PHP_EOL;
            $log .= 'Total de emails que faltam: ' . count( $this->addresses ) . PHP_EOL;
            if( count( $this->addresses ) == 0 ) {
                $this->completedAt = time();
                $this->deactivate();
                // Método para notificar por email quando o envio terminar.
                $this->sendNotificationToMailingCompleted();
                $log .= 'Envio de mailing concluído';
            }
        }
        $this->save();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $log .= $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $log;
}
```

A cota aumenta gradativamente conforme o bom uso do serviço, sendo assim, elaborei o código acima de forma a identificar esse aumento e trabalhar com a maior taxa de envio possível.

Nas configurações iniciais da Amazon ( 10.000 emails em 24 horas com taxa de envio de 5 emails por segundo) seriam 300 emails por minuto, ou seja, levaria em média 33 minutos para enviar 10.000 emails. Pode levar algumas horas a mais utilizando a maneira que cito aqui, dependendo do limite definido na constante `MAX_QUOTA_USAGE`.

Alem disso, a Amazon possui políticas rígidas para envio de email, e possuir uma lista de email limpa, isto é, sem muitos emails inválidos é essencial. Para resolver esse problema, implementei outra tarefa que executa verificando todos os emails de 15 em 15 dias, e armazenando informações indicando se o email é válido ou não.

O SDK da Amazon possui [método que possibilita essa verificação (verifyEmailIdentity)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_verifyEmailIdentity). Porem este método deve ser chamado com o intervalo de pelo menos 1 segundo.

Comment: Valeu pela boa pergunta e resposta. Me ajudou em um projeto que estou fazendo!