# Recolher dados do Google Analytics para tabelas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics-api, google-api, revisão-de-código

Tenho visto muitos exemplos de como exportar dados do [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) para outros formatos, bem como manter os dados exportados atualizados, mas nenhum até ao momento serviu para exportar os dados para MySQL atendendo aos seguintes problemas:

- Ultrapassagem dos limites de consultas;
- Processo demora horas para manter os registros atualizados;
- Processo torna-se inviável à partir dum determinado número de registros porque o dia só tem 24h.

Até ao momento a minha implementação está neste formato:

```
         ┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
         │ Por cada registro na base de dados local │
         └────────────────────┬────────────────────┘
                              │
            ┌─────────────────┴──────────────────┐
            │ Enviar URL para o Google Analytics │
            └─────────────────┬──────────────────┘
                              │
┌─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┐
│ Com estatísticas recebidas, atualizar base de dados local │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Isto funciona bem, mas para ultrapassar os problemas listados, é preciso fazer uso de pausas:

```php
while ($registoLocal = $sth->fetch()) {

    if (time_nanosleep(0, 500000000) === true) {
        // comunicar com o Google Analytics
    }
}
```

O que se reflete num tempo +/- fixo por cada `$registoLocal`, atualmente em 2 segundos o que nos deixa com um máximo de 43200 consultas por dia.

Além disso temos os limites da [API do Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas):

- 50,000 pedidos por projeto por dia
- 10 consultas por segundo por IP

## Código em uso

Incluir dependências e instanciar a API:

```
/* API dependencies
 */
require_once('caminho/para/Google_Client.php');
require_once('caminho/para/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php');

/* Create client object and set app name
 */
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('O nome da minha aplicação'); // app name

/* Set assertion credentials
 */
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        'mega-super-grande-email-da-google@developer.gserviceaccount.com', // API Service Account Email Address
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
        file_get_contents('caminho/para/o/ficheiro/O nome da minha aplicação.p12')  // downloaded keyfile
    )
);

/* Other settings
 * Access the Google Cloud Console and view the Web App-project details:
 * https://cloud.google.com/console
 */
$client->setClientId('outro-mega-super-grande-email-da-google@developer.gserviceaccount.com'); // Client ID for web application Email Address
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setUseObjects(true);
```

Ligação à base de dados local:

```
/* Connection access details
 */
$dbcon = array(
    "host"     => "localhost",
    "dbname"   => "nomeBaseDados",
    "username" => "utilizador",
    "password" => "password"
);

/* Connect to the database
 */
$dbh = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.$dbcon['host'].';dbname='.$dbcon['dbname'].';',
    $dbcon['username'],
    $dbcon['password'],
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT               => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES utf8"
    )
);

/* Prepare query for Insert
 */
$sqlInsert = "
INSERT INTO press_statistic_analytics
    (id, press_id, ga_profile_id, ga_sessions, ga_pageviews, ga_percentNewVisits, date_created, date_updated)
VALUES
    (null, :press_id, :ga_profile_id, :ga_sessions, :ga_pageviews, :ga_percentNewVisits, :date_created, :date_updated)";

$queryInsert = $dbh->prepare($sqlInsert);

/* Prepare query for Update
 */
$sqlUpdate = "
UPDATE press_statistic_analytics SET
    ga_sessions = :ga_sessions,
    ga_pageviews = :ga_pageviews,
    ga_percentNewVisits = :ga_percentNewVisits,
    date_updated = :date_updated
WHERE press_id = :press_id
AND ga_profile_id = :ga_profile_id ";

$queryUpdate = $dbh->prepare($sqlUpdate);

/* Get all Articles
 */
$sth = $dbh->query("
SELECT
    press_i18n.press_id,
    press_i18n.title,
    press_i18n.slug
FROM press_i18n
ORDER BY press_i18n.id DESC");

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Por cada registo local, comunicar com o Google Analytics e recolher informação:

```
while ($article = $sth->fetch()) {

    if (time_nanosleep(0, 500000000) === true) {

        /* Create service and get data
         */
        $gaProfileID = 'ga:11111111';
        $startDate = '2000-01-01';
        $endDate = date("Y-m-d", time());
        $metrics = 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:percentNewVisits';
        $optParams = array(
            "filters" => "ga:pagePath==/".$article->slug
        );

        $service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

        /* Query Google and process results
         * to a more usable array.
         */
        try {

            // Get data
            $results = $service->data_ga->get($gaProfileID, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);

            $googleAnalyticsArr = array();

            if (isset($results) && is_object($results) && count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

                $headersArr = (Array)$results->getColumnHeaders();

                $i=0;

                foreach ($results->getRows() as $row) {

                    foreach ($row as $cell) {

                        $googleAnalyticsArr[$headersArr[$i]->name] = htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_NOQUOTES);

                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Update or insert the collected data
             */
            $sthSelectExistent = $dbh->query("
                SELECT *
                FROM press_statistic_analytics
                WHERE press_id = ".$article->press_id."
                AND ga_profile_id = '".$gaProfileID."'
            ");
            $sthSelectExistent->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $rowSelectExistent = $sthSelectExistent->fetch();

            /* Prepare data
             */
            $ga_sessions = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:sessions"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:sessions"] : 0;
            $ga_pageviews = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:pageviews"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:pageviews"] : 0;
            $ga_percentNewVisits = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:percentNewVisits"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:percentNewVisits"] : 0.00;

            if (is_object($rowSelectExistent)) {

                $queryUpdate->execute(
                    array(
                        "ga_sessions"         => $ga_sessions,
                        "ga_pageviews"        => $ga_pageviews,
                        "ga_percentNewVisits" => $ga_percentNewVisits,
                        "date_updated"        => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        "press_id"            => $article->press_id,
                        "ga_profile_id"       => $gaProfileID
                    )
                );
            }
            else {
                $queryInsert->execute(
                    array(
                        "press_id"            => $article->press_id,
                        "ga_profile_id"       => $gaProfileID,
                        "ga_sessions"         => $ga_sessions,
                        "ga_pageviews"        => $ga_pageviews,
                        "ga_percentNewVisits" => $ga_percentNewVisits,
                        "date_created"        => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        "date_updated"        => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        catch (apiServiceException $e) {

            // Handle API service exceptions.
            //$error = $e->getMessage();
            var_dump($e);
        }
        catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {

            // Handle API service exceptions.
            //$error = $e->getMessage();
            var_dump($e);
        }
    }
}
```

## Pergunta

> Como otimizar este processo de recolha das estatísticas de cada URL presentes no Google Analytics para a base de dados local em MySQL de forma a evitar pausas forçadas no *script* e sem ultrapassar os limites atualmente impostos pela Google ?

Comment: Você tem na base de dados todas as páginas rastreadas pelo Analytics? Não seria possível fazer uma única requisição ao serviço, sem filtragem por página, e depois fazer o loop de correspondência com o seu banco?

Comment: Foi o que pensei aquando da primeira implementação, mas eles tem um limite de 1000 resultados por consulta, o que me fez desistir desse método! Como não vem tudo só implementando algum controlo para ir buscar 999, depois mais 999, etc... Poderá vir a ser uma solução, carece mais testes para apurar a sua viabilidade.

Comment: [Quinhentinhos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/223/zuul?tab=bounties) :D

Comment: @brasofilo Hmmm... bounties é bom, mas gastando a REP numa resposta que resolva o problema! A Bounty vai trazer respostas tipo "isto deve funcionar" e a REP vai ser gasta sem viabilidade de solução... Mas... Se tens uma solução, avisa, que meto a maior bounty possível neste tópico ;)

Comment: Ah, that's part of the gamble, pode ser que apareça uma boa, pode ser que não :) Eu achei muito interessante o problema e pensei colocar uma, mas aí vi de quem era, jejeje

Comment: @Zuul acho que você pode adatar esse script para usar a implementação de cron que fiz para o envio de email do SES http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9958/enviar-email-em-massa-usando-amazon-ses mas qual a utilidade disso? quero dizer qual a ferramenta que pretende ter?

Comment: Eu entendi que você faz URL por URL por causa da limitação de 1000 registros por consulta, no caso, o que garante que uma URL não teria mais que 1000, isso é levado em consideração?

Comment: É, parece que esta recompensa vai ficar "pro governo" mesmo. :D Ou será que o @Ricardo vai fazer uma resposta nos 45 segundos do segundo tempo? :)

Comment: Pois é @gustavox, meu comentário foi pelo seguinte: Se existe X urls para serem rodandas (impossível mudar isso) e o google estipula Y segundos de intervalo então o tempo mínimo é (X*Y)+(seu processamento). Agora, se o fato de uma uma URL ter mais de 1000 registros é levado em conta e tratado então podemos começar a pensar em reduzir as URLs... Ou entrar em contato com o google mesmo para ver se eles tem alguma resposta para isso.

Comment: Bom, analisando seu problema tenho algumas perguntas:

Comment: Bom, analisando seu problema tenho algumas perguntas: Há possibilidade de separa o codigo de busca e gravação em uma pagina separada sem while apenas uma vez? Se sim para a pergunta anterior porque não agendar essa pagina para ser chamada pelo agendador de tarefas do seu servidor? Outra coisa, considerou utilizar ao invez de while o multi curl, acredito que fica bem melhor o código.

Comment: Então @Ricardo eu realmente não entendo o suficiente pra opinar aqui...  é uma pena que o Zuul não tenha aparecido pra te dar um feedback, ele é um top user aqui do SOpt, então imagino que ele não tenha visto ainda os comentários, porque caso contrário tenho certeza que ele responderia... Eu ofereci a recompensa principalmente porque sempre que entro na área de perguntas sem respostas acho uma judiação uma pergunta tão bem avaliada não ter nenhuma resposta, porque acho que uma solução aqui ainda pode ser útil pra mim no futuro, e pelo próprio aprendizado que sempre tiro de perguntas assim...

Comment: Como acho que realmente ninguém vai arriscar uma reposta, e que essa recompensa está perdida mesmo (o que NÃO quer dizer que vou dar a recompensa pra qualquer resposta que aparecer agora, ainda mais que não vou ter tempo de ver como a comunidade vai avaliar a resposta...), então vou fazer diferente, e vou deixar aqui garantida uma recompensa de 100 pontos para qualquer resposta que for aceita pelo Zuul e/ou que tenha mais de 10 votos favoráveis. Essa recompensa eu vou conceder após a resposta (o que é aceito e até sugerido pelo sistema, diga-se) ter sido aceita ou bem votada.

Answer (score 2):

Solução proposta:

1 . Criar uma coluna com a data da ultima vez que consultou no google os dados do `article`

`ALTER TABLE press_i18n
ADD COLUMN date_ga DATE NULL`

2 . Mudar o script que busca todos os `articles` para pegar pela data o ultimo não atualizado

```
$sth = $dbh->query("
SELECT
    press_i18n.press_id,
    press_i18n.title,
    press_i18n.slug
FROM press_i18n
WHERE date_ga < DATE(NOW()) OR date_ga IS NULL
ORDER BY press_i18n.id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

3 . Dar `UPDATE` da `date_ga` do registro buscado da base logo abaixo

```
// Pegamos o artigo
$article = $sth->fetch();

if(!$article) {
    echo "Não encontrou article";
    break;
}

echo "Article: " . $article->press_id;

$sthUpdate = "UPDATE press_i18n SET date_ga = DATE(NOW()) WHERE press_i18n.press_id = :press_id";
$queryUpdateGa = $dbh->prepare($sthUpdate);

$queryUpdateGa->execute(
    array(
        "press_id" => $article->press_id
    )
);
```

4 . Alterar código de comunicação com o Google para sempre executar um registro da article por vez

```
$gaProfileID = 'ga:11111111';
$startDate = '2000-01-01';
$endDate = date("Y-m-d", time());
$metrics = 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:percentNewVisits';
$optParams = array(
    "filters" => "ga:pagePath==/".$article->slug
);

$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

try {

    // Get data
    $results = $service->data_ga->get($gaProfileID, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);

    $googleAnalyticsArr = array();

    if (isset($results) && is_object($results) && count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        $headersArr = (Array)$results->getColumnHeaders();

        $i=0;

        foreach ($results->getRows() as $row) {

            foreach ($row as $cell) {

                $googleAnalyticsArr[$headersArr[$i]->name] = htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_NOQUOTES);

                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Update or insert the collected data
     */
    $sthSelectExistent = $dbh->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM press_statistic_analytics
        WHERE press_id = ".$article->press_id."
        AND ga_profile_id = '".$gaProfileID."'
    ");
    $sthSelectExistent->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $rowSelectExistent = $sthSelectExistent->fetch();

    /* Prepare data
     */
    $ga_sessions = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:sessions"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:sessions"] : 0;
    $ga_pageviews = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:pageviews"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:pageviews"] : 0;
    $ga_percentNewVisits = isset($googleAnalyticsArr["ga:percentNewVisits"]) ? $googleAnalyticsArr["ga:percentNewVisits"] : 0.00;

    if (is_object($rowSelectExistent)) {

        $queryUpdate->execute(
            array(
                "ga_sessions"         => $ga_sessions,
                "ga_pageviews"        => $ga_pageviews,
                "ga_percentNewVisits" => $ga_percentNewVisits,
                "date_updated"        => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                "press_id"            => $article->press_id,
                "ga_profile_id"       => $gaProfileID
            )
        );
    }
    else {
        $queryInsert->execute(
            array(
                "press_id"            => $article->press_id,
                "ga_profile_id"       => $gaProfileID,
                "ga_sessions"         => $ga_sessions,
                "ga_pageviews"        => $ga_pageviews,
                "ga_percentNewVisits" => $ga_percentNewVisits,
                "date_created"        => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                "date_updated"        => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
            )
        );
    }
}
catch (apiServiceException $e) {

    // Handle API service exceptions.
    //$error = $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {

    // Handle API service exceptions.
    //$error = $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
```

5 . Partindo do principio que essa página tem um nome (e pode ser acessada externamente) podemos criar uma pagina PHP para chamar ela ou agendar no CRON para essa pagina ser chamada a cada X tempo
Como não sei qual é seu servidor vou criar uma pagina que chama a pagina de comunicação com o google a cada 1 segundo, teoricamente podemos duplicar as requisições no google.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">

<?php 
    @file_get_contents( "http://seuservidor/pasta/arquivo_que_comunica_com_o_google.php" );     
?>
```

- A solução não foi testada pois não tenho o banco de dados da pergunta, mais faço um processo parecido aqui na minha empresa e funciona pelo crontable aproximadamente 150 mil requisições/dia
- Acredito que utilizando o `CRONTAB` dá para aumentar e muito o numero de requisições no google.
- Em caso de dúvidas estou à disposição no chat

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é uma limitação da ferramenta por capacidade e sim por preço ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas ).

Eles fizeram o limite de busca baseado em uma requisição a cada 1.7 segundos que seria um tempo bom para uma rotina. Por isso burlar isso vai ser um pouco complicado se não for pagar a api. A do Adwords funciona da mesma forma e as DSP pagam um bom dinheiro para usar as Exchanges.

Na tela de API pode ser ligado o faturamento para aumentar essa cota. E lembrando que se vocês está usando a conta free ainda tem o problema de amostra de dados na API ( Na paga também, mas eles dizem que não ).
Lembrando que se tiver usando o premium pode utilizar o Big Query que vai te dar os arquivos mais mastigados.

Algumas ferramentas que você pode usar como:
- Webtrends;
- Piwik ( Analytics Open Source );
- At Internet;

Sei que essa não é exatamente a resposta que você esperava, mas o limite disso existe para que eles consigam monetizar o que eles suportam de dados. 
Tente com o Piwik vai ter controle total dos dados FREE, e ainda pode implementar com Javascript via tag manager da mesma forma.

---

Esqueci de comentar fora o real time, os outros relatórios demora 24 horas ( Sem SLA ) na versão free e 4 horas na versão premium. Pode fazer a request de hora em hora quando houver diferença nos dados.