# Como criar um agendador de tarefa sem utilizar cron e sem utilizar wordpress

Tags: php, cron, agendamento

Preciso criar um método automático para agendar meu sistema de email marketing, para disparar emails automaticamente, sem usar o navegador. Hoje esse meu sistema está utilizando o cron, e toda vez que eu habilito ele em um servidor, preciso configurar a url da rotina do script no cron. Gostaria de torná-lo independente dessa configuração manual.

Esta é a configuração manual do tempo que tenho que habilitar para disparar o evento:

`GET /emkt/urldosistema/ [ 5 * * * * ]`

Toda ajuda é bem-vinda, aqui está a minha ferramenta que estou trabalhando (em ZF 1.12): 
**https://github.com/ivanferrer/EmailMarketing**

Tem alguma restrição se eu usar algo similar a isso?

```
$file = '/cronfile/mycron_execute.txt';

$addcron = "5 * * * * GET /emkt/urldosistema/";
file_put_contents($file, $addcron);
exec('crontab ' . $file, $output, $return);
if ($return === 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: O servidor é remoto? Por que você poderia utilizar o agendador de tarefas dele mesmo para executar o script. Eu tive o mesmo problema e resolvi assim.

Comment: Alternativa ao cronjob (linux) ou schtask(windows), que eu conheça, não tem. O que vai poder fazer é alguma gambiarra com "loop infinito".  Qual a dificuldade em usar o cron? Não está funcionando? Verificou se precisa de alguma autenticação ou permissão de acesso? Normalmente no painel de administração do servidor de hospedagem oferece isso.

Comment: Se você puder por uma chamada para a sua aplicação na inicialização da máquina, não precisa do cron. Pode controlar os intervalos direto na aplicação. A vantagem seria ter o controle independente do cron, e poder mudar o comportamento da tarefa sem precisar de acesso administrativo (a não ser na instalação). Isso pelo fato de PHP poder rodar em loop quando é executado pelo console, basta desabilitar o timeout. Isso evita do script precisar de acesso administrativo também. E se for pelo console, o loop (desde que feito com sleep para nao consumir recursos à toa) definitivamente não é gambiarra.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ivan, recentemente desenvolvi um sistema parecido utilizando Node.js e PHP.

Segue o link do projeto no [Github](https://github.com/thiagothaison/TaskRunner)

O projeto consiste basicamente em dois módulos, send eles

- Um Servidor Node.js, responsável por executar as tarefas agendadas
- O Projeto em PHP, responsável por salvar as tarefas agendadas

O Servidor Node.js deve possuir os módulos `cron` e `wget` instalados.

O Projeto PHP possui uma interface de configuração do servidor Node.js, podendo facilmente parar ou iniciar o servidor a qualquer momento.

Vamos ao que interessa!

[image: Menu do Projeto]

- Servidor Node.js : Configuração do Servidor Node.js
- Servidores de Execução : Para a execução de arquivos .exe, .bat, etc
- Grupos : Os grupos onde as tarefas podem estar
- Agendamentos : As tarefas agendadas

---

## Servidor Node.js

[image: Tela : Servidor Node.js]

Nesta tela configuramos o servidor Node.js.
Quando a aplicação está no ar e o servidor Node.js está rodando, neste exemplo ele criará um arquivo chamado `cron.js` no diretório `C:\Users\ttpinto\Documents\NodeJS`. O Servidor rodará sob o endereço `http://localhost:3001`.

Clicando em `Iniciar Servidor`, colocamos o Servidor Node.js no ar.

[image: Servidor On-line]

Se acessarmos a URL `http://localhost:3001`, veremos a seguinte página:

[image: Servidor On-line]

---

## Servidores de Execução

Neste tela, cadastramos os servidores que poderão executar arquivos (.bat, .exe, .jar) agendados. Para isso, devemos informar obrigatoriamente o `host`, `usuario de rede` e a `senha`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a execução de arquivos em servidores diferentes do que está rodando o apache, é necessário instalar e configurar o [PSExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx).

---

## Grupos

Nesta tela criamos grupos de execução. A principal funcionalidade dos grupos é que quando desativamos um grupo, todas as tarefas agendadas dentro dele são desativadas automaticamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Agendamentos

É nesta tela que a mágica acontece.

[image: Agendamentos]

Olhando os agendamentos cadastrados, temos 3 ativos e 1 inativo. Porém, o segundo agendamento faz parte de um grupo que está inativo, portanto também não será executado. Sendo assim, apenas os dois últimos serão executados.

O botão `play` força a execução de um agendamento, independente se ele está ativo ou não.

---

## Adicionando um agendamento

Nesta tela cadastramos os agendamentos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na parte de `Configuração do Agendamento` existe uma interface que permite a configuração do `cron`, por exemplo:

Para criar um agendamento para ser executado todos os dias às 12:00:00hrs
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado. :-)

Comment: Ok, toda ajuda é bem-vinda.

Comment: Eu ainda não comecei a mexer com NodeJS, mas muito obrigado pela dica, vou estudar seu sistema, ao meu ver parece bem funcional, porém vi que há algumas configurações para um localhost a partir do Windows, eu estou acostumado a trabalhar meu desenvolvimento em plataforma Linux, espero que isso não seja nenhum impedimento quando for configurar servidor do Node.

Answer (score 2):

## Automatização de instalação

Uma solução para o problema da instalação manual, seria automatizar via shell script. O Script faria a importação do banco de dados, configuraria o STMP automaticamente, criaria os arquivos necessários e corrigiria as permissões.

## A lógica

1. Perguntar sobre as configurações necessários para [o arquivo de configurações](https://github.com/ivanferrer/EmailMarketing/blob/master/public/index.php);
2. Escrever o arquivo já configurado;
3. Perguntar sobre os dados de acesso ao banco de dados;
4. Criar arquivo [`application.ini`](https://github.com/ivanferrer/EmailMarketing/blob/master/application/configs/application.ini.template);
5. Importar [arquivos SQL](https://github.com/ivanferrer/EmailMarketing/tree/master/application/configs/mysql);
6. Agendar cron task;
7. Revisar permissões das pastas do sistema.

## O script

Criando o arquivo:

```
touch install.sh
# ou
nano install.sh
# ou
vi install.sh
```

O conteúdo do script:

```
#!/bin/bash

##
# Função de cabeçalho
##
header() {
    clear
    echo "-------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "| Instalação do EmailMarketing                        |";
    echo "| (c) Ivan Ferrer - http://www.tocadigital.com.br       |"
    echo "-------------------------------------------------------"
    echo
}


##
# Função para substituição de valores de constantes do arquivo index.php
##
replaceConstants() {
    sed --in-place "s/'$1', '.*'/'$1', '$2'/" $3
}



##
# Função para substituição de valores do arquivo application.ini
##
replaceApplicationFile() {
    sed --in-place "s/$1/$2/" $3
}



##
# Configurando usuário
##
USERNAME_EMKT="admin"
PASSWORD_EMKT=""
CONFIRM_PASSWORD_EMKT=""

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 1 / 8 ] Configurando o usuário de acesso"
echo
echo

# obtendo o usuário
echo -n " - Nome de usuário: "
read USERNAME_EMKT

# Solicita a senha enquanto for vazia ou não for confirmada corretamente
while [ -z $PASSWORD_EMKT ] || [ $PASSWORD_EMKT != $CONFIRM_PASSWORD_EMKT ]
do
    echo -n " - Senha de acesso: "
    read -s PASSWORD_EMKT
    echo

    echo -n " - Confirme sua senha: "
    read -s CONFIRM_PASSWORD_EMKT
    echo

    if [ -z $PASSWORD_EMKT ]
    then
        echo
        echo "A senha informada está em branco. Para garantir segurança, informe uma senha."
        echo
    elif [ $PASSWORD_EMKT -ne $CONFIRM_PASSWORD_EMKT ]
    then
        echo
        echo "As senhas digitas não são iguais, por favor digite novamente."
        echo
    fi
done



##
# Configuração de SMTP
##
NAME_SENDER_CLIENT=""
SMTP_ACCOUNT=""
EMAIL_SENDER_CLIENT=""
EMAIL_SENDER_SIS=""
PASS_SENDER_SIS=""
PORT_MAILER=587
SSL_PROTOCOL="tls"

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 2 / 8 ] Configurando o SMTP"
echo
echo

echo -n " - Nome completo do usuário: "
read NAME_SENDER_CLIENT

echo -n " - Host do SMTP: "
read SMTP_ACCOUNT

echo -n " - Porta do SMTP (587): "
read PORT_MAILER

if [ -z PORT_MAILER ]
then
    PORT_MAILER=587
fi

echo -n " - Protocolo do SMTP (tls): "
read SSL_PROTOCOL

if [ -z SSL_PROTOCOLR ]
then
    SSL_PROTOCOL="tls"
fi

echo -n " - Email de acesso ao SMTP: "
read EMAIL_SENDER_SIS

echo -n " - Senha de acesso ao SMTP: "
read PASS_SENDER_SIS

echo -n " - Email de resposta: "
read EMAIL_SENDER_CLIENT



##
# Criando arquivo de configuração do sistema
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 3 / 8 ] Criação do arquivo de configuração do sistema"
echo

echo "Criando o arquivo..."

chmod 777 public/index.php
replaceConstants "USERNAME_EMKT" "$USERNAME_EMKT" public/index.php
replaceConstants "PASSWORD_EMKT" "$PASSWORD_EMKT" public/index.php

replaceConstants "NAME_SENDER_CLIENT" "$NAME_SENDER_CLIENT" public/index.php
replaceConstants "EMAIL_SENDER_CLIENT" "$EMAIL_SENDER_CLIENT" public/index.php
replaceConstants "EMAIL_SENDER_SIS" "$EMAIL_SENDER_SIS" public/index.php
replaceConstants "PASS_SENDER_SIS" "$PASS_SENDER_SIS" public/index.php
replaceConstants "PORT_MAILER" "$PORT_MAILER" public/index.php
replaceConstants "SMTP_ACCOUNT" "$SMTP_ACCOUNT" public/index.php
replaceConstants "SSL_PROTOCOL" "$SSL_PROTOCOL" public/index.php

echo "Arquivo criado com sucesso!!!"
echo
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read



##
# Configuração de banco de dados
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 4 / 8 ] Configurando o banco de dados"
echo

DATABASE_HOST="127.0.0.1"
DATABASE_NAME=""
DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
DATABASE_PASSWORD=""

echo -n " - Host do banco de dados (127.0.0.1): "
read DATABASE_HOST

if [ -z DATABASE_HOST ]
then
    DATABASE_HOST="127.0.0.1"
fi

echo -n " - Nome do banco de dados: "
read DATABASE_NAME

echo -n " - Usuário (root): "
read DATABASE_USERNAME

if [ -z DATABASE_USERNAME ]
then
    DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
fi

echo -n " - Senha: "
read DATABASE_PASSWORD



##
# Criando o arquivo application.ini
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 5 / 8 ] Criando o arquivo de configuração do banco de dados"
echo

echo "Criando o arquivo..."

cp application/configs/application.ini.template application/configs/application.ini

replaceApplicationFile "<%username%>" "$DATABASE_USERNAME" application/configs/application.ini
replaceApplicationFile "<%password%>" "$DATABASE_PASSWORD" application/configs/application.ini
replaceApplicationFile "<%database%>" "$DATABASE_NAME" application/configs/application.ini
replaceApplicationFile "<%servidor%>" "$DATABASE_HOST" application/configs/application.ini

echo "Arquivo criado com sucesso!!!"
echo
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read



##
# Importando banco de dados
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 6 / 8 ] Importando o banco de dados"
echo

echo "Criando banco de dados..."
mysql --host=$DATABASE_HOST --user=$DATABASE_USERNAME --password=$DATABASE_PASSWORD < application/configs/mysql/database_create_command.sql
echo "Criando tabelas..."
mysql --host=$DATABASE_HOST --user=$DATABASE_USERNAME --password=$DATABASE_PASSWORD < application/configs/mysql/database_create_tables_emkt.sql

cho "Importação realizada com sucesso!!!"
echo
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read



##
# Configuração de banco de dados
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 7 / 8 ] Agendamento de tarefas"
echo

echo "Agendando tarefas..."

# Editar esta linha de acordo com a necessidade do CRON
crontab -l > mycron
echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/projeto/meu-script.php" >> mycron
crontab mycron
rm mycron

echo "Agendamento feito com sucesso!!!"
echo
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read



##
# Configuração de banco de dados
##

# Chama a função header
header
echo "[ 8 / 8 ] Definindo as permissões de arquivos"
echo

echo "Definindo permissões de pastas..."
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

echo "Definindo permissões de arquivos..."
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

cho "Permissões definidas com sucesso!!!"
echo
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar..."
read




##
# Fim da execução
##
header
echo
echo
echo "Instalação concluída com sucesso!!!"
echo "Pressione qualquer tecla para finalizar..."
read

# Finaliza a execução
exit 0
```

## Loop em php

Uma outra solução é a criação de um loop em php para executar de tempos em tempos a tarefa desejada.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // executa o seu código
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
    sleep(60); // aguarda 1 minuto
}
```

para executar o código basta executar o comando via terminal

```
php script.php
```

Porem este método não te dá a mesma segurança do Cron, pois o script pode parar de executar e você perceber tarde demais.

*Se a automatização via shell resolver seu problema, por favor altere o título da pergunta, retirando o desejo de uma solução sem cron*

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma tabela no banco de dados (estou usando MySQL). Registrando as tarefas no banco de dados é possível facilmente habilitar e desabilitar uma tarefa, assim como alterá-la quando for necessário.

```
CREATE TABLE `cron_task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `minute` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `hour` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `weekday` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `first_execution` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_execution` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Utilize uma interface para padronizar as classes de tarefas.

```
interface ICronTask {
    public static function add( ICronTask $task );
    public function activate();
    public function deactivate();
    public function executeTask();
    public function makeLog( $content );
}
```

Onde o método `add` serve para salvar uma tarefa, `activate` e `deactivate` para ativar e desativar a tarefa, `executeTask` conterá o contexto de execução da tarefa, seja envio de email, requisição de url, backup, ou seja lá o que mais, e o método `makeLog` para gerar logs personalizados para a execução das tarefas.

Crie uma classe abstrata para implementar os métodos básicos para todas as tarefas.

```
abstract class CronTask implements ICronTask {
    public $id;
    public $description;

    public $minute;
    public $hour;
    public $day;
    public $month;
    public $year;
    public $weekday;

    public $type;
    public $priority;

    public $active;
    public $first_execution;
    public $last_execution;

    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;

    public $execution_start;
    public $execution_end;

    public function __construct( $id = null ) {
        // caso o $id possua valor, busque informações no banco sobre a tarefa
        // e preencha todos os atributos.
    }

    public final static function add( ICronTask $task ) {
        // Salve no banco de dados e chame o método save()
    }

    public final function activate() {
        // Atualize a tarefa no banco para ativar
    }

    public final function deactivate() {
        // Atualize a tarefa no banco para desativar
    }

    public function makeLog( $content ) {
        // Salve o log da tarefa
        // Se precisar de um log personalizado para a tarefa, sobrescreva esse método.
    }

    public final function executeTask() {
        // Executa a tarefa
        $this->execution_start = round( microtime(true), 4 );
        $content = $this->execute();
        $this->execution_end = round( microtime(true), 4 );
        $this->makeLog($content);
    }

    public final function isNow() {
        // Faz a verificação da hora de execução, garantindo que deve ser executada
        // no momento em que for chamado.
        return (
            $this->parserTime($this->minute, 'i')   &&
            $this->parserTime($this->hour, 'H')     &&
            $this->parserTime($this->month, 'm')    &&
            $this->parserTime($this->day, 'd')      &&
            $this->parserTime($this->weekday, 'w')
        );
    }

    private function parserTime( $value, $element ) {
        // Obtem o tempo atual
    $time = date( $element );

    // Verifica se o valor é igual à "*" representando toda momento.
    if( $value == '*' ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Separa os conjuntos de tempos separados por vírgula
    $groups = explode( ',', $value );
    foreach ( $groups as $part ) {
        // Verifica se é um intervalo composto. Ex: "*/5" ou "20-40/2"
        // Se é um intervalo compost, deverá retornar true se o valor atual
        // estiver dentro do intervalo definido antes da barra, e na frequência
        // definida após a barra.
        if( strpos( $part, '/' ) ) {
            $groupsInterval = explode( '/', $part );
            // Verificando a frequência
            $frequency = $time % $groupsInterval[1] == 0;

            // Verificando o intervalo
            $interval = explode( '-', $groupsInterval[0] );
            $intervalResult = false;
            if( $interval[0] == '*' ) {
                $intervalResult = true;
            } else {
                $intervalResult = ( $time >= $interval[0] && $time <= $interval[1] );
            }
            return $frequency && $intervalResult;
        }

        // Verifica se é um intervalo simples. Ex: "10-50"
        // Se é um intervalo, deverá retornar true se o valor atual estiver
        // dentro desse intervalo.
        if( strpos( $part, '-' ) ) {
            $interval = explode( '-', $part );
            return $time >= $interval[0] && $time <= $interval[1];
        }

        // Se for um número simples verifica se é o tempo certo
        if( $time == $part ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    abstract protected function execute();
    abstract protected function save();
}
```

E um exemplo de implementação de uma classe de tarefas seria

```
class CronTaskTest extends CronTask {
    public $type = 'Test';
    public $priority = 0;

    protected function execute() {
        return 'Tarefa executada com sucesso';
    }

    protected function save() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A classe principal que será executada a todo instante verificando as tarefas, ficou implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
class Cron {
    public static function execute() {
        $tasks = self::getTasks();
        foreach ( $tasks as $task ) {
            if( $task->isNow() ) {
                $task->executeTask();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getTasks() {
        try {
            $tasks = // Busque todas as tarefas ativas ordenadas por prioridade DESC;

            $return = array();
            foreach ( $tasks as $record ) {
                $taskName = 'CronTask' . $record['type'];
                require_once __DIR__ . '/tasks/' . $taskName . '.php';
                $return[] = new $taskName( $record['id'] );
            }
        } catch ( PDOException $exception ) {
            die( $exception->getMessage() );
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Crie um arquivo PHP para executar as tarefas chamando o método `Cron::execute()`.
Agende no CRON

```
# crontab -e
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/projeto/meu-script.php
```

Comment: Vou tentar executar a sua solução, teria algum problema se eu criar o campo `created_at timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`?

Comment: Teria não, mas creio que o MySQL não aceita Not null em campos do tipo timestamp. Já tive problemas com isso antes, vou até corrigir isso no meu post depois

Comment: O processo todo eu entendi, achei interessante a forma que você fez de gravar no banco, porém ainda está usando o `crontab`. Eu dei uma estudada, e vi que existem maneiras de fazer isso usando somente o banco de dados: [Se quiser uma referência sobre isso, aqui tem mais informações](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html), e [aqui tem como criar um evento](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) vou postar a solução como resposta aqui.

Comment: Interessante a parte do eventos no MySQL. A solução que passei usa uma tarefa de cron job, mas te permite executar várias tarefas de forma mais simples de controlar, e quem sabe até criar uma interface para manipular suas tarefas. Para um envio de e-mail marketing fica bem interessante, a resposta original foi dada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9958/enviar-email-em-massa-usando-amazon-ses/11974?noredirect=1#comment98199_11974

Comment: A resposta original atende bem a pergunta. Porém ainda estou sentindo falta de uma solução alternativa ao cron. Talvez tenha que ser algo feito em java. Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso.

Comment: Não tinha me apegado ao detalhe que quer não precisar configurar o cron toda vez que mudar o de servidor. Ajudaria então se por uma página que executar já fizer a instalação do cron? Uma página de instalação, ou um painel que permita instalar ou desinstalar uma crontask? Pois as alternativas em Java, ou shell script, não vai mudar o fato de ter que fazer alguma coisa para agendar a tarefa. Por exemplo em Java, terá que executar o app, se fizer um script que rode com tempo indeterminado com um sleep tambem.

Comment: Então a solução que vejo para facilitar é uma página que já faça a instalação do cron se não estiver ativo. Exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037176/install-a-cron-job-with-a-php-script

Comment: @marcusagm se não for uma aplicação para usar pelo browser, não precisa do cron, desde que possa por na inicialização da máquina. Aí bastaria usar sleep() no loop principal, como vc disse. A vantagem do sleep é você ter controle sobre ele sem precisar de acesso administrativo à maquina. Para mexer no cron pelo script, o script precisa ser admin, o que é um furo imenso em termos de segurança.

Comment: Pois é aí tem várias soluções desde Java, shell, e até mesmo no PHP. Fica fácil resolver o problema, mas pelo que vi a intenção é querer facilitar a instalação e migração. Executar loops é arriscado, pois se ocorre um erro a execução pode ou não ser interrompida até ocorrer alguma manutenção. O cron já está implementado cercando esses problemas, inclusive para relatórios via e-mail em caso de erros ou output na execução. Ir pra esse lado seria reinventar a roda... Sei lá rs, por isso queria saber dele se facilitaria a vida na instalação criar uma página que automatize

Comment: as vezes para contornar o problema de segurança, criar um shell script para automatizar a instalação resolva o problema

Comment: @marcusagm, obrigado pela sugestão e criação do arquivo shell, é uma coisa a mais que poderei acrescentar à ferramenta. Tenho planos de criar uma ferramenta de instalação para o usuário comum, a partir da própria ferramenta, irei criar um diretório `install`, com o passo a passo, via web mesmo. Mas a questão mesmo é fechar o navegador e ele continuar disparando, sem ter que configurar o cron.