# Servidor com Timer em PHP

Tags: php, script, cron, timer

Gostaria de utilizar o PHP para rodar um servidor de monitoramento, que executa periodicamente (Ex: hora em hora) uma checagem, mas sem depender de Cron ou Agendador de tarefas, a não ser que seja para dar "start" nesse servidor PHP, pois assim, além de não ficar preso a plataforma, posso controlar na aplicação as configurações de horarios, periodos, etc.
Existe algo nesse sentido que eu possa usar?

Comment: O PHP não persiste, ele precisa ser chamado, não acho que seja possível somente com PHP.

Comment: Acredito que isso possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102890/33194 este projeto ai é um agenciador de tarefas Nodejs que pode ser utilizado para disparar ações, por exemplo, você pode disparar um script PHP com ele. Assim não ficará preso a plataforma.

Comment: Resolvi disponibilizando uma URL que dispara todo o resto. A unica configuração é colocar na CRON ou Agendador de tarefas pra atingir com o CURL esta url de 1 em 1 minuto (CRON), ou 5 e 5 minutos (Win). Só vou precisar agora controlar com banco os horarios de execuções hehehe