# Como fazer um agendamento contando de tempo a tempo?

Tags: php

Bom galera gostaria de saber como faço para criar um agendamento simples, exemplo coloco um script para rodar a cada 5 minutos, pela logica ele executa a primeira vez e espera mais 5 minutos para rodar denovo pulando 5 min tentei fazer mas não deu muito certo. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda

```
if(time() - $row['time'] == $row['tempo'] + $row['agenda'] && $row['agenda'] >= 30){

        if($row['tempo'] <= $row['tempo'] + $row['agenda']){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `agendamento` SET `tempo` = tempo+".$row['agenda'].", `tempo_anterior` = tempo_anterior+".$row['agenda']." WHERE `id` =".$row['id'].";"); //ADICIONA + SEGUNDOS NO BANCO DE DADOS
        }

}else if($row['tempo'] > $row['agenda'] && $row['agenda'] >= 30){

    // EXECUTA MINHA FUNÇÃO SE CONTAR NO TEMPO CERTO

}
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes ? Colocar o código que já tentou na pergunta.. Quer fazer isso somente com *PHP* ? Vai executar o *PHP* como ? Chamadas via *Ajax* ? *Cron* ? Sem detalhes fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: fiz uma edição e coloquei o código que comecei a fazer pelo php ele usa o banco de dados para adicionar as informações

Comment: Essa verificação `$row['tempo'] <= $row['tempo']` está errada, como pode  tempo ser menor ou igual a tempo ? A biblioteca `mysql_*` foi descontinuada, seu uso não é recomendado, leia [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/60376).

Answer (score 2):

Você tem duas possibilidades usando o CRON do linux ou elaborar um script que roda indefinidamente.

## Executar script eternamente

Para rodar o script indefinidamente basta fazer

```
set_time_limit(0);
while (true) {
    // código a ser executado de tempo em tempo
    if ( $quit === true ) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(300);
}
```

Observe que coloquei uma condição de parada, tornando possível a interrupção da execução.

Essa maneira é a pior de se fazer por vários motivos. O PHP não foi feito para executar infinitamente, pois o uso de memória pode aumentar consideravelmente conforme o tempo de execução aumenta. Outra desvantagem é a manutenção, pois o script pode parar e você não ficar sabendo. Utilize este método apenas em último caso.

## Agendar utilizando o CRON do linux

A outra maneira mais recomendada, é utilizar o CRON ou o agendador de tarefas do windows.

Esta maneira é a mais utilizada, pois o script executa de tempos em tempos e mesmo caso ocorra algum erro, o script será executado novamente no tempo programado.

Para adicionar sua tarefa e agendar a execução, entre no terminal do servidor e digite:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Irá abrir um arquivo de texto onde poderá colocar as tarefas agendadas seguindo alguns padrões. Em seu caso, a linha a ser adicionada ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
*/5 * * * * php ~/caminho/para/o/script.php
```

Caso queira que seja chamada um URL em específico, terá que usar o comando wget na tarefa ficando assim:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O - http://www.exemplo.com.br/script.php > /caminho/do/arquivo/para/armazenar/a/saida.txt
```

Para saber mais sobre o CRON, leia esta pergunta:

[Configurar Cronjob para executar de 5 em 5 minutos, quando estiver dentre 5 a 20 horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/configurar-cronjob-para-executar-de-5-em-5-minutos-quando-estiver-dentre-5-a-20/124519#124519)

Caso queira controlar melhor seu agendamento de tarefas, escrevi uma resposta explicando como criar uma ferramenta pelo PHP para gerenciar as execuções.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103262/3938