# Como criar cron jobs via php

Tags: php, email, cron

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde ele enviara emails programados usando PHP. Então irá ter uma interface gerencial que o usuário poderá escolher em quantos dias irá querer que envie os emails.

Agora a minha dúvida é, como posso criar um cron através de quantos dias o usuário digitou em um formulário?

Alguma outra sugestão que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Já que você está desenvolvendo o sistema, se for linux a hospedagem, isto é se for web, já que faltaram detalhes... Uma forma de fazer isso seria agendar uma tarefa cron a ser executada a cada x minutos, ela então acessará seu arquivo .php que executa a rotina e então daí pra frente é programação: o script verifica se há algo a ser feito e realiza os disparos, caso contrário encerra a execução, um return; (encerra tudo), porém depende o que for isto poderá consumir um processamento valioso de seu servidor.

Comment: Com NodeJS dá pra fazer também, veja isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93788/como-criar-um-agendador-de-tarefa-sem-utilizar-cron-e-sem-utilizar-wordpress Não vou realizar uma resposta porque pode não ser o que você está procurando.

Comment: @TiagoBoeing acho que ele quer que o usuário possa agendar um envio de email via programação (um painel por exemplo), creio que algo como isto: https://github.com/MUlt1mate/cron-manager

Comment: Sim, fazendo que o cron execute o script dele a cada x minutos, bastaria o script ver se há algo a ser feito, baseado no que o usuário definiu. Vai dar trabalho, mas fora isto ele teria que fazer o php se comunicar via ssh e agendar a tarefa cron.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Quero criar um painel mesmo onde o usuário teria todo o controle para o agendamento. 
Também estou utilizando servidor Windows.