# Enviar anexos pelo Amazon SES ( Função SendEmail )

Tags: php, amazon-aws, ses

Olá,

Eu estou usnando uma biblioteca (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-email-2010-12-01.html#sendemail) da Amzon para enviar email em um sistema em que trabalho, porém parei em um problema:

Eu estou usando a classe SESClient e sua função SendEmail.

Eu não consegui encontrar nada referente a como enviar anexo, e preciso enviá-los.

Pesquisei na documentação da Amazon e não encontrei respostas.

Se alguém poder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Atenciosamente, Renan.

Comment: Será que não ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9958/enviar-email-em-massa-usando-amazon-ses?rq=1

Comment: Muito obrigado Marconi, mas esse tópico não é exatamente o que eu quero fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem duas opções:

1. Usar uma biblioteca de envio de emails via SMTP e [apontá-la para seu SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html)
2. Criar um email em baixo nível (raw), codificando todo o formato de se incluir um arquivo manualmente (todo o processo de codificar o arquivo em base64, dividir em blocos, etc). Eu encontrei [alguém que já fez isso](http://www.righthandedmonkey.com/2013/06/how-to-use-amazon-ses-to-send-email-php.html) e talvez possa ser um ponto de partida para você.

Eu sinceramente tentaria a opção 1 primeiro.

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio. Acabei fazendo da segunda forma, fazendo um email "cru", desde o cabeçalho até o envio de um upload. Muito obrigado por ter respondido.

Comment: Beleza @renan-porto. Agradeço se marcar minha resposta como a solução.